# Photos stored in iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, graphics, storage

There are hundreds of pictures that have been stored in my "cloud"... how is it possible for me to view the pictures that are stored there ?

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.apple.com/icloud/photos/

> Access all your photos from anywhere.
>   iCloud Photo Library automatically keeps all your photos in iCloud, so you can access them on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, Mac, Apple TV, or iCloud.com, or download them to your PC. And when you edit a picture using Photos, your changes are uploaded to iCloud and visible everywhere. Just go to iCloud settings, tap Photos, and enable iCloud Photo Library.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all you iCloud Photos by logging in to Apple online iCloud account.

GO TO [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com)

CLICK ON THE CIRCLE RED ICON [image: iCloud Photos]